# How to pass a TextBlock^ to a class constructor

Tags: winrt-xaml, c++-cx

In **myPage.xaml.cpp** I would like to instantiate an object of a ref class, let's call it myClass, passing to its constructor a Textblock^ called myTextblock that I have defined in **myPage.xaml**
I do it like this

```
myPage::myPage() : m_myClass(myTextblock)
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

where m_myClass is a private property of type myClass.

In **myClass.cpp** I have

```
myClass::myClass(Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::TextBlock^ tb) : m_tb(tb)
{
}
```

where again m_tb is a private property of type TextBlock^.

The idea is to have **myClass.cpp** the possibility to change the Text property of the Textblock using a function

```
void myClass::myFunction()
{   
    //do stuff
    m_tb->Text=L"something else";
}
```

The problem is I am not able to instantiate properly the m_tb property of myClass (that is to point the Textblock in **myPage.xaml**), it is always nullptr. I even tried to create 
a ref pointer to myClass in myPage and doing

```
myPage::myPage() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    myClass^ m_myClass = ref new myClass(myTextblock);
}
```

but with the same negative result. What I am doing wrong? What is the right way to inizialize myClass and its Textblock^ property?

Comment: The first snippet does not work because myClass gets constructed too early.  Second snippet is better but has a simple typo, you made it a local variable.  Delete `myClass^`.  Don't be afraid to write `this->m_myClass = ...`, IntelliSense is your friend.

Comment: Well, I did.  If you want to preserve this Q+A (why?) then just post the answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, it is a way to show appreciation and then I think it would be rude to take merit for something I didn't do. If you are ok with it I can leave the answer as it is. Thank you again.